# ¿Cómo puedo generar una tabla de cálculo como excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, tablas

Estoy intentando generar una tabla con pandas similar a la siguiente en Excel:

[![Archivo ejemplo en excel]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo generar esta tabla que contiene cálculos internos?

```
#Swi, Sor variables para calculo 
Swi = 0.091 
Sor = 0.26
Swcorey = pd.Series ([Swi,float(Swi+(1-Sor-Swi)/10)], name='Swcorey')
Swcorey
```

Comment: Hola Ricardo, ¿qué fórmula se sigue para el cálculo de las columnas aa partir de solo Swi y Sor? Se de dónde sale la columna Swe por tu fórmula, pero ¿y las otras dos?

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, las otras dos columnas salen de estas ecuaciones.     
Siendo Krw1 = 0.26, Kroi = 0.95, Exw = 1, Exo=3.02
Formulas :  Krw Corey = (Krw1) * ( (Swcorey - Swi )/(1-Sor -Swi))^Exw. 
Kro Corey = (Kroi) * ( (1-Swcorey- Sor )/(1-Sor -Swi))^Exo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dada la naturaleza iterativa del proceso de cálculo de `Swecory` al depender del valor previamente cal, no es una operación fácilmente vectorizable, pero podemos usar un ciclo con Python sin más:

```
import pandas as pd


N = 10 # Número de columnas a calcular  
Swi = 0.092 
Sor = 0.26

last_swi = Swi
swcorey = [Swi] + [last_swi:= round(last_swi + (1 - Sor - Swi) / 10, 4) for _ in range(N)]
swcorey = pd.Series(swcorey)
```

> ```
> >>> swcorey
>
> 0     0.0920
> 1     0.1568
> 2     0.2216
> 3     0.2864
> 4     0.3512
> 5     0.4160
> 6     0.4808
> 7     0.5456
> 8     0.6104
> 9     0.6752
> 10    0.7400
> dtype: float64
> ```

Las otras dos columnas, si solo dependen de las constantes y de la columna Swcorey si son vectorizables:

```
import pandas as pd


N = 10 # Número de columnas a calcular  
Krw1 = 0.26
Kroi = 0.95
Exw = 1
Exo=3.02
Swi = 0.092 
Sor = 0.21

last_swi = Swi
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Swe": [Swi] + [last_swi:= round(last_swi + (1 - Sor - Swi) / 10, 4)
                         for _ in range(N)]
     })

df["Krw Corey"] = Krw1 * ((df["Swe"] - Swi ) / (1 - Sor - Swi)) ** Exw 
df["Kro Corey"] = Kroi * ((1 - df["Swe"] - Sor) / (1 - Sor - Swi)) ** Exo
```